# Firebase's scrypt version don't give the same hash as save

Tags: firebase, hash, passwords, firebase-authentication, scrypt

I'm here because I'm working on this [repo](https://github.com/xeewi/firebase-scrypt).

When i compare the hash from firebase and this hash i created using the [utility created by firebase](https://github.com/firebase/scrypt) for the same password using the same salt and the same parameters, they are not the same.

Is someone getting any idea for a sample of solution ? I'm totally stuck and i do not understand what is happening here ^^'

Thx !

EDIT : the hash function ( [aslo here](https://github.com/xeewi/firebase-scrypt/blob/master/src/firebaseScrypt.js#L17) )

```
  hash (password, salt) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  exec(
    `${__dirname}/../scrypt/scrypt "${this.signerKey}" "${salt}" "${this.saltSeparator}" "${this.rounds}" "${this.memCost}" -P <<< "${password}"`,
    { shell: '/bin/bash' },
    (error, stdout) => error ? reject(error) : resolve(stdout),
  )
})
```

}

EDIT 2 : I forgot to say that, but I export users password hash using the admin sdk.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies, but why are you using the command line scrypt instead of one of the many npm packages that do the same thing? (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scryptsy)

Comment: Could you please provide an example and your code which does the hashing?

Comment: @apaatsio Because firebase using a modified version of scrypt, and there is no js implementation of it. So i'm trying to create it haha

Comment: @LazerBass you can see it on the repo, but i editing the message it's maybe more easy

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase documentation states that "on successful sign-in, Firebase re-hashes the user's password with the internal Firebase hashing algorithm". If you've already logged in you would see a unique hash so I do not think you should be expecting an exact match to your project's keys.

Comment: Maybe i must say it before, but i export users from firebase using the admin sdk, i'm not logged as this users

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself : the probleme was coming from the way I export users. I was using JS Admin SDK and the `listUsers()` function, but apparently that's not return to you the right password hash (maybe for security, I asked i will update this post when I know).

If you want to export your users and use `firebase-scrypt` to verify their password, export your users using [`firebase-tools`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) and the command [`auth:export`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth)